# No new line when piping into xclip

Tags: bash, xclip

Is there something I can do so that whenever I pipe something into `xclip` it does not include a new line at the end?
As a workaround, I am using `echo -n $(CMD_TO_COPY) | xclip`, but it's kind of annoying having to type all of this each time I want to copy something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the man page, `xclip` has a `-rmlastnl` (`-r`) option that will do exactly what you want:

```
echo hello | xclip -i -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Though `xclip` since version 0.13 does have an option to remove a trailing newline as already noted by larsks, you could also always define a function that does the processing you want like:

```
clipboard() { printf %s "$(cat -- "$@")" | xclip -sel c; }
clipboard() { printf %s "$(cat -- "$@")" | xsel -b; }
```

(here, command substitution removes ***all*** trailing newline characters and in some shells including `bash`, also all the NUL ones).

Or to remove only one trailing newline like `xclip -r` does:

```
clipboard() { cat -- "$@" | perl -pe 's/\n$// if eof' | xclip -sel c; }
```

And use as:

```
cmd | clipboard
clipboard <<< "$var"
clipboard some-file and-some-other
```

In any case, [using `echo`](/q/65803), or [unquoted command substitutions](/q/68694) as in your *<strike>`echo -n $(CMD_TO_COPY)`</strike>* approach is not correct.